# For IEEE ACCESS Template Error encountered in table code when complied. Error message: Undefined control sequence. \sisetup

Tags: tables, tabularx, threeparttable, xtable

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}


\titlepgskip=-15pt

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Evaluation of the proposed}
\label{tab:Y_Forecast}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \sisetup{round-mode=places,
             round-precision=2,
             table-format=1.2,
             }
\begin{tabula}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}  l  *{4}{S} }
    \toprule
 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Proposed and benchmark forecast models} \\
    \cmidrule{2-5}
\thead{Months}
        & {\thead{SDPSO-ELM \\ MAPE \\(\%)}}
            & {\thead{F-RBF-CNN\\ MAPE \\(\%)}}
                & {\thead{SSA-SVM-CS\\ MAPE \\(\%)}}
                     & {\thead{FA-HELF \\ MAPE\\(\%)}} \\
\midrule
    Jan & 2.22 & 1.67 & 1.55 & 0.414\\

\midrule
Avg.& 2.12 & 1.79 & 1.44 & 0.410\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\EOD

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You forgot to load `siunitx` package.

Comment: @ Zarko I used siunitx then generate another error

Comment: In your MWE is not present.

Comment: @ Zarko with MWE it still not working

Comment: @ Zarko. Now it works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your MWE has many issues:

- you haven't defined content of `maketitle` (in your case it is not relevant, so remove it from MWE)
- you did not load packages `booktabs` and `makcell` for tables
- you did not load package `siunitx` for use of `S` columns
- `\begin{tabula}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}  l  *{4}{S} }` is wrong, correct is `\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{4}{S} }` and of course table should be end by `\end{tabular*}`

Corrected MWE is:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}  % <---
\begin{document}
\titlepgskip=-15pt
%\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Evaluation of the proposed}
\label{tab:Y_Forecast}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \sisetup{round-mode=places,
             round-precision=2,
             table-format=1.2,
             }
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{4}{S} }
    \toprule
 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Proposed and benchmark forecast models} \\
    \cmidrule{2-5}
\thead{Months}
        & {\thead{SDPSO-ELM \\ MAPE \\(\%)}}
            & {\thead{F-RBF-CNN\\ MAPE \\(\%)}}
                & {\thead{SSA-SVM-CS\\ MAPE \\(\%)}}
                     & {\thead{FA-HELF \\ MAPE\\(\%)}} \\
\midrule
    Jan & 2.22 & 1.67 & 1.55 & 0.414\\

\midrule
Avg.& 2.12 & 1.79 & 1.44 & 0.410\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\EOD

\end{document}
```

[image]